# How to check if WebView Javascript Interface is available?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, interface

is there any proper way to check in JavaScript inside the WebView, if the JavaScript Interface is available/defined?

My Idea was to define a checking method in the interface, that (if available) could be called and simply return a true. Isn't there a proper 'official' way to do that? Because if the interface is not available/undefined, it will throw an error.

I'm using Android, that's why Java code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppinterface(this),"InterfaceName");

@JavascriptInterface
public void isInterfaceAvailabe (){
   return true;
}
```

And in Javascript:

```
function hasJavaScriptInterface () {
   if (InterfaceName.isInterfaceAvailable()){
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to check whether `InterfaceName` is actually exported, that is -- does it present as a property on the `window` object. You can do it several ways:

```
if ("InterfaceName" in window) ...
```

or

```
if (window.InterfaceName) ...
```

or

```
if (typeof window.InterfaceName === "function") ...
```

Because if you just try invoking a non-defined property, you will get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: window.InterfaceName is not a function`

Comment: if(window.InterfaceName) works for me, that should be marked as answer.